# Change column type to int in Pandas Python - without warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My attempt: df['uid'] = df.uid.astype(int)

Which works...! However, Python doesn't like it:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
>   using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

My question - what's the "best practice" of how to do this simple code?

Research so far:

[Pandas: change data type of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/pandas-change-data-type-of-columns)

[A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961014/a-value-is-trying-to-be-set-on-a-copy-of-a-slice-from-a-dataframe-warning)

Attempts:

1. df[df['uid']].astype(int)

...some of the links say to use iloc but I can't see how that can be used here...

Comment: It's not the `astype(int)`  
It's the way you constructed `df` prior.

Comment: I've read the other pages - I'm still having trouble reproducing their solutions aren't exactly what I'm trying to do (I think?). One method is to make a copy, but I'm trying to avoid making a copy and do it in place since the dataframe I have is huge.

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean by df prior? I'm new at this. Thanks! @piRSquared

Comment: `df['uid'] = df.uid.astype(int)` implies `df` already existed.  It was how it was constructed that left it as a `copy`.

Comment: If you want to do this using loc, you would do it this way :

`df.loc[:, 'uid'] = df['uid'].astype(int)`

Comment: @dmdip wow that was exactly what i was looking for. so in plane english - is that "out of all columns, select UID column and then astype that column of the ORIGINAL DF." right?

Comment: @jhub1 : Your statement suggests that the .loc merely changed the type of the column to int. I am not sure if pandas recognises that this is all that has to be done, or whether it creates a copy of that column (in memory), changes that copy to int, and then copies it back to replace the existing uid column.